# anaconda-navigator not launching from Anaconda Powershell Prompt

Tags: windows-10, powershell, python, anaconda

In Windows 10 Enterprise, after installing Anaconda3-2019.03 64 bit, I get the following error when I try to launch anaconda-navigator:

```
(base) PS C:\> anaconda-navigator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cbaker2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 202, in <module>
    from PySide import __version__ as PYSIDE_VERSION  # analysis:ignore
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PySide'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\cbaker2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Scripts\anaconda-navigator-script.py", line 6, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.app.main import main
  File "C:\Users\cbaker2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\app\main.py", line 22, in <module>
    from anaconda_navigator.utils.conda import is_conda_available
  File "C:\Users\cbaker2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\anaconda_navigator\utils\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from qtpy.QtGui import QIcon
  File "C:\Users\cbaker2\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qtpy\__init__.py", line 208, in <module>
    raise PythonQtError('No Qt bindings could be found')
qtpy.PythonQtError: No Qt bindings could be found
```

Comment: Can you follow [this analysis, called as _Anaconda (Pyside / PyQt is required)_](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2765), @Chad?

Answer (score -2):

conda install pyside2 fixed the issue for me